# How to recreate my table in database in Django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, datatable

**i created a table in sqlite3 database by migrate command and then deleted it manually from database
how can i recreate the table in database**

I tryed maigrate command again but its show   `No migrations to apply.`
pls someone tell how do i recreate the table in automatic way(by commands)

Comment: Are your models managed or not? Have you run `makemigrations` before running `migrate`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fake the migration that creates the table with:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake myapp 00XX_last_migration
```

This fakes migrations up to the last migration.

Then it should just be a matter of running migrate again

```
python manage.py migrate
```

As a side note, this is the theory to do it, however there are ways this could go wrong depending on your project. I would definitely try this first in a local environment to make sure it works before going ahead and doing this in a production environment.